# Output that looks like something else in Python

Tags: python

Today I had some free time and I started to play a little bit with Python. I tried running an apparently simple piece of code which looks like this:

```
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(i * ++i)
for a[i] in a:
    print(a[i])
```

Now, as you probably may expect, the *obvious* output should be something like:

```
0
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
```

But it actually isn't. What I do get instead when I run it, is:

```
0
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
64
```

How is this working ?

Comment: You know Python doesn't support `++` decrement? And why on earth are you iterating over `a` like that? Add `print(a)` inside the second loop and it should be obvious why you get the output you do; `i` is always `9` after the first loop, so you assign to `a[9]` on each step of the loop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is not my code snippet. I just ran into it. I didn't expect to work. But I kinda' tried understanding how and why this it's working. The code runs successfully with Python 3. I'd just like an explanation for the output ^^

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it work (or run, at least)? It's valid syntactically, it's just pointless. Why don't you ask whoever wrote it why they did so? Or spend some time investigating it yourself (e.g. put some more `print`s in: https://repl.it/CWD1/0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down to pieces.

```
a = []
```

Empty list initialized, so far, so good.

```
for i in range(10):
    a.append(i * ++i)
```

Two mistakes here. First of all, `++i` is `+(+i)` which essentially is no op. Secondly, any changes done inside for-loop body for `i` name won't survive to next iteration.

`for o in seq` essentially does this:

1. Pointer is kept internally and this is where it keeps track of currently "active" member in iteration
2. On beginning of each loop

   a) pointer is incremented to next element

   b) value of that element is assigned to `o`

So in this step, on beggining of each iteration `range(10)` is asked for next number and `i = THAT_NEXT_NUMBER` assignment is done.

Now let's go to that bizzare second loop:

```
for a[i] in a:
    print(a[i])
```

We know that after first loop `i` is 9 (last value assigned to name `i`) and `a` is `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 46, 49, 64, 81]`.

Since for loop is essentially "ask and assign" described above, step by step operations are:

1. Ask list for first element, assign it to `a[i]` which is `a[9]`, go to for-loop body. List is: `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 46, 49, 64, 0]`, printed value is `a[i]` = `a[9]` = `0`
2. Ask list for second element, assign it to `a[i]` which is `a[9]`, go to for-loop body. List is: `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 46, 49, 64, 1]`, printed value is `a[i]` = `a[9]` = `1`

---

9. Ask list for second-to-last element, assign it to `a[i]` which is `a[9]`, go to for-loop body. List is: `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 46, 49, 64, 64]`, printed value is `a[i]` = `a[9]` = `64`
10. Ask list forlast element, assign it to `a[i]` which is `a[9]`, go to for-loop body. List is: `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 46, 49, 64, 64]` (9th element in list is replaced with 9th element in list), printed value is `a[i]` = `a[9]` = `64`.

And there is your result.

Comment: Thanks @Rogalski. Perfectly explained

Answer (score 6):

```
for i in range(10):
    a.append(i * ++i)
```

Python doesn't have a `++` operator. `++i` is just the unary `+` operator twice, which is a no-op.

```
for a[i] in a:
    print(a[i])
```

That is a really bizarre loop. It's mixing up `for`...`in` syntax with indexing. The typical way to loop over a list is:

```
for item in a:
    print(item)
```

As for why 64 is printed twice with the original code: when the first loop finishes `i` is 9. The second loop is therefore equivalent to:

```
for a[9] in a:
    print(a[9])
```

For each element in the list `a`, it assigns that element to the last position in `a` (say what?), and then prints that last element. This works pretty much the same as a `for item in a` loop until you reach the end, at which point the phantom's twisted face is revealed.

Because it's been assigning to `a[9]` the whole time, `a[9]` doesn't retain its original value of 81. When you get to the end it's been overwritten by the previous value, 64. That's why 64 is printed twice.

Comment: Nice explanation. Now I understand

Answer (score 0):

When you want to print out `a` you should do:

```
for element in a:
    print(element)
```

The problem with your code is that

```
for a[i] in a
```

overwrites `a[i]` every time the loop runs. `i = 9` in this case because it comes from the first loop. So your second loop prints everything correctly and at the same time assigns that value to `a[9]` This is why at the end of the loop your last element is `64` again.